# Use a for-loop to create list-objects for each file from file directory

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list of files created:

```
d <- list.files(path = "C:/data/", pattern = ".TextGrid")
```

I want to run the TextGrid() command of the textgRid package on each of these files. This will create a list object for each file. These I want to save as list-object with their filename as object name.

I have tried:

```
for (file in d) {file <- TextGrid(paste0("C:/data", file))}
```

Thx for your help

Comment: which language, perhaps tag with that

Comment: true...in R. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code as a start:

```
for (file in d) {
    tmp <- TextGrid(paste0("C:/data/", file))
    assign(file, tmp)
}
```

Comment: perfect, only the backslach was missing `for (file in d) {
    tmp <- TextGrid(paste0("C:/data/", file))
    assign(file, tmp)
}`

Comment: Which backslash?

Comment: the backslash in the file path

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that uses lapply instead of a loop, I've never used the textgRid package so hopefully this works.

```
d <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.TextGrid$"),TextGrid)
names(d)<-paste0("C:/data",list.files(pattern = "\\.TextGrid$")
```